# Draw object on image and drag image

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an image like a small map. I want to do something like
1. drag it like http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-an-image-tutorial/ 
2. draw some object (such as: line, point) on image (object attached with image while image drag)


I try to do something such as using http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-label-tutorial/ ,etc. but it's not attached with image when i drag image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are looking at KineticJS examples.

Here is an example of how to do your map plus points and lines in KineticJS.  Using this library might be simpler to get started with instead of learning the complexities of dragging in canvas alone.

In this example code, be sure to put the URL to your map instead of img1.src="yourMap.jpg".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {margin: 0px;padding: 0px;}
      canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

      var img1=new Image();
      img1.onload=function(){
          createDragMap();
      }
      img1.src="yourMap.jpg";

      function createDragMap(){

            var map = new Kinetic.Shape({
              drawFunc: function(canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();

                // draw the map and a border around the map
                context.drawImage(img1,0,0);
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(0,0,img1.width,img1.height);
                context.stroke(this);

                // add your points to the map here
                // for example...
                context.rect(23,67, 4,4);          
                context.rect(153,87, 4,4); 
                context.moveTo(23,67);
                context.lineTo(153,87);         

                // fill and stroke must be done last!
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
              },
              width: img1.width,
              height: img1.height,
              stroke:"blue",
              strokeWidth: 2,
              draggable:true
            });
            layer.add(map);
            stage.add(layer);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i don't downvote your answer, but i can't draw sun or anything on rocket. i want rocket as background that it can drag and i can draw anything into it

Answer (score 0):

You have to track the mousedown and mouseup events on the canvas.

- On mousedown get the mouse coordinates, make them relative to the canvas, test if they are inside of the image you drew on the canvas (point-in-box).
- If the mouse is inside the image: on mouseup redraw the image on the canvas based on the delta between the mousedown coordinates and the mouseup coordinates.